# Redirect visitors from my website to other wesbsite using htaccess only by time

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect my website visitors to another websites basing of time.
For exapmple between 00:00 to 10:00 any visitor to my wbsite will redirect to xxx.com and any visitor from 10:00 to 15:00 visitrs will redirect to yyy.com

I need to do this using htaccess not php

Comment: So, are you aware of any time manipulation functions in Apache or you're just hoping they exist?

Comment: What have you tried so far, I see nothing to copy & paste.. And I better hope not you're redirecting to xxx.com

Comment: @Xorifelse ssshh, let the OP do the answering :)

Comment: This site works best if you provide us with information on what you've tried and hopefully with supporting code samples, so far it appears that you've tried nothing. Why are you limited to htaccess?

Comment: The problem is I'm using a hosting service that limit me to receive just 5000 visitors daily to my website, but to avoid website suspension after the 5000 visitors, I receive 4000 visitors then I using htaccess to send visitors to another website, manually (the visites redirect by htaccess not counted)
@Scuzzy

Comment: @N.B. I'm using a webhoting :/ so I can't change apache configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%{TIME_HOUR}` in your "RewriteCond" rules...

Taken from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/advanced.html#time-dependent

> Description:
>
> ```
> We wish to use mod_rewrite to serve different content based on the time of day.
> ```
>
> Solution:
>
> ```
> There are a lot of variables named TIME_xxx for rewrite conditions. In conjunction with the special lexicographic comparison patterns <STRING, >STRING and =STRING we can do time-dependent redirects:
>
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond   "%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN}" >0700
> RewriteCond   "%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN}" <1900
> RewriteRule   "^foo\.html$"             "foo.day.html" [L]
> RewriteRule   "^foo\.html$"             "foo.night.html"
>
> This provides the content of foo.day.html under the URL foo.html from 07:01-18:59 and at the remaining time the contents of foo.night.html.
> ```

Comment: And how about redirect all websites traffic to another external page?